# Find and pull information from another sheet to a designated one

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a macro that takes information from column B in a sheet titled "Push," and then looks at column A in the "Official" sheet to see if there is a matching number. If there is, it takes the information from column C of the corresponding column in the "Official" sheet and puts it into the corresponding column D in the "Push" sheet.

The logic is supposed to be as follows:

1. If "Push" column B value matches a column A value in "Official" then
2. Copy corresponding text in cell C in "Official" then
3. Paste text into corresponding column D in "Push"

The below code worked. A month later it doesn't work. It doesn't give me any errors, I press "run" and nothing happens. I made sure macros were enabled in my spreadsheet, tried closing and reopening.

The only thing I can think of is my code somehow got changed.

```vb
Sub AcceptedConditions()
    Dim Cl As Range
    Dim Dic As Object
    
    Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    With Sheets("OFFICIAL")
        For Each Cl In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            Dic(Cl.Value) = Cl.Offset(, 2).Value
        Next Cl
    End With
    With Sheets("Push")
        For Each Cl In .Range("B2", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Dic.exists(Cl.Value) Then Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = Dic(Cl.Value)
        Next Cl
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint (F9) on the first line and then run it. You can then check your variables and step to the next line using F8.

Comment: Remember that it's dependent on data being in columns A and B, so if those columns have moved recently, that would be the problem.

Comment: Hm. Trying to do the breakpoint doesn't do anything, either. The columns and their contents are the same as they last time I used the workbook.

Comment: If it doesn't stop on the breakpoint, then the code is not running. How are you trying to run it? to be clear, the "first line" i refer to is the one with `CreateObject` - not the Dim lines. When you press F9 the line should turn red.

Comment: I have been trying to run it by clicking the little "play" button and F5 while having the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" window open. The line does turn red like you say it should, but it's highlighted and then I click play and nothing happens. I thought maybe it wasn't running at all so I just put a bunch of gibberish in the code and it gave me an error.

Comment: I would look into VBasic's suggestions in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Classic VBA Lookup Using a Dictionary

- IMO, your code should run as-is, or an error should occur. Here are the issues I considered some obviously not being relevant to the code running correctly.

**Issues**

- If you don't specify the workbook, the code could run on the wrong one i.e. if there is another with the same worksheets open. I used `ThisWorkbook`, the workbook containing this code (and the worksheets). Note how the worksheets are qualified with the `wb` variable.
- I added the line `dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare` to ignore case i.e. `BALL` and `ball` are the same.
- If you're planning to loop over cells then don't let Excel decide what will be looped over, but specify it explicitly with `.Cells` appended to the range.
- By using `If dict.Exists(cString) Then` in the source part, if there are duplicates (there shouldn't be), you are ensuring that the first found value is written to the dictionary. Otherwise, it's the last.
- If the lookup data aren't (all) strings, it may be preferable to convert them to strings using `CStr` and using a string variable to do so.
- You haven't specified what to do if a value is not found. I chose to clear the contents of those cells.
- If you add to show a message box after the code has run, you will know that the code has run and that e.g. the battery hasn't run out on your mouse or whatnot.
- BTW, it will seem that nothing is happening every time nothing was changed in the data since it will just overwrite the old data with the same values. Hopefully, you have deleted the cells in the return column, column `D`, before running the code and claiming that nothing is happening.

**A Quick Fix**

```
Sub AcceptedConditions()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case
    
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Source
    With wb.Sheets("OFFICIAL")
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Cells
            dict(CStr(cell.Value)) = cell.Offset(, 2).Value
        Next cell
    End With
    
    ' Destination
    With wb.Sheets("Push")
        For Each cell In .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Cells
            If dict.Exists(CStr(cell.Value)) Then ' found
                cell.Offset(, 2).Value = dict(CStr(cell.Value))
            Else ' not found
                cell.Offset(, 2).ClearContents
            End If
        Next cell
    End With

    MsgBox "Accepted conditions updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**More**

- The above VBA is e.g. a replacement for the following formulas:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFICIAL!C2:C8,MATCH(B2:B11,OFFICIAL!A2:A8,0)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFICIAL!C2:C8,XMATCH(B2:B11,OFFICIAL!A2:A8)),"")
=XLOOKUP(B2:B11,OFFICIAL!A2:A8,OFFICIAL!C2:C8,"")
```

[image]

**Alternatives**

- Alternatively, you could do the following:

```vb
Sub AcceptedConditionsMATCH()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim slrg As Range ' Lookup
    With wb.Sheets("OFFICIAL")
        Set slrg = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Cells
    End With
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dlrg As Range ' Lookup
    With wb.Sheets("Push")
        Set dlrg = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Cells
    End With

    ' Using 'Match'.
    With Application
        dlrg.Offset(, 2).Value _
            = .IfError(.Index(slrg.Offset(, 2), .Match(dlrg, slrg, 0)), "")
    End With

    ' Microsoft 365
    
    ' Using 'XMatch'.
'    With Application
'        dlrg.Offset(, 2).Value _
'            = .IfError(.Index(slrg.Offset(, 2), .XMatch(dlrg, slrg)), "")
'    End With

    ' Using 'XLookup'.
'    With Application
'        dlrg.Offset(, 2).Value = .XLookup(dlrg, slrg, slrg.Offset(, 2), "")
'    End With

    MsgBox "Accepted conditions updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

- You could also write a spilling formula instead:

```vb
Sub AcceptedConditionsFORMULA()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim slrg As Range, sName As String
    With wb.Sheets("OFFICIAL")
        Set slrg = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        sName = .Name
    End With
    
    ' Destination
    
    With wb.Sheets("Push")
        Dim dlrg As Range ' Lookup
        Set dlrg = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        
        Dim Formula As String
        
        ' Using 'MATCH'.
        Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('" & sName & "'!" _
            & slrg.Offset(, 2).Address(0, 0) & ",MATCH(" _
            & dlrg.Address(0, 0) & ",'" & sName & "'!" _
            & slrg.Address(0, 0) & ",0)),"""")"
    
        ' Microsoft 365
    
        ' Using 'XMATCH'.
'        Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('" & sName & "'!" _
'            & slrg.Offset(, 2).Address(0, 0) & ",XMATCH(" _
'            & dlrg.Address(0, 0) & ",'" & sName & "'!" _
'            & slrg.Address(0, 0) & ")),"""")"
     
        ' Using 'XLOOKUP'.
'        Formula = "=XLOOKUP(" _
'            & dlrg.Address(0, 0) & ",'" & sName & "'!" _
'            & slrg.Address(0, 0) & ",'" & sName & "'!" _
'            & slrg.Offset(, 2).Address(0, 0) & ","""")"
        
        'Debug.Print Formula
        dlrg.Cells(1).Offset(, 2).Formula2 = Formula ' spills
        With dlrg.Offset(, 2)
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    
    End With

    MsgBox "Accepted conditions updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Your fix worked like a charm. I followed your advice and added a Message Box to appear in my original code and it popped up. So, it's running... and I did delete the contents prior to making this post so that wasn't my issue. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Thanks. Glad it worked out for you. Now if you implement each of the changes in your code, only one at a time, and each time check the code, you will eventually find out what is wrong with it. I would surely like to hear about it.